# hashvalue is same for all strings wether created using literal or new

Tags: java, string

I created 3 string 2 with string literals and one with using new. But when I am printing the hash code for them, it's giving same hash code. I am confused as how it can return same hash code. Please find the example below.

```
public class StringTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String str = "abc";
        String str1 = "hfdjkfhs";

        System.out.println("hashValue str:::" + str1.getClass().hashCode());
        System.out.println("hashValue str:::" + str.getClass().hashCode());

        String str2 = new String("def");

        System.out.println("hashValue:::" + str2.getClass().hashCode());

    }

}
```

Output :-

hashValue str1:::366712642

hashValue str:::366712642

hashValue str2:::366712642

Comment: No, you are printing the hashcode of the `String` `Class` each time, not the `String` objects. Try `str1.hashCode()` for example.

Comment: and it should be the same as `String.class.hashCode()`...

Answer (score 6):

You are printing the hashcode for the `String` class, not for the created `String` object.

Instead of:

```
str.getClass().hashCode()
```

You should have:

```
str.hashCode()
```

Comment: Thnx I got my mistake

Answer (score 2):

You are using:

```
Object.getClass()
```

which returns the class object, then getting the hash code for that object. This is called reflection. Since the class object is the same for each instance, you get the same hash code.

You probably want the hash code of each instance, which you already have references to, so instead use:

```
str.hashCode();
str1.hashCode();
str2.hashCode();
```

More info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html